# SharedPreferences - Formatting string Warning

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I am using **SharedPreferences** to store three Variables.

vib_a_strength_shared, 
vib_b_strength_shared, 
vib_c_strength_shared

My onCreate Method looks like this:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends MainActivity {

private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

private static int vib_a_strength;
private static int vib_b_strength;
private static int vib_c_strength;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(
            "de.somecode.bachelorarbeit", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.apply();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings_screen);
    checkConnection();
    back();
    vib_a_listener();
    vib_b_listener();
    vib_c_listener();
}
```

Then I have three equivalent methods like:

```
    private void vib_a_listener() {
    vib_a_strength = sharedPreferences.getInt(getString(R.string.vib_a_strength_shared), 120);
    final TextView vib_a_text_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vib_a_strength);
    vib_a_text_view.setText(getString(R.string.strength_text, vib_a_strength));
    SeekBar vib_a_seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.vib_a_seek_bar);
    vib_a_seekBar.setMax(255);
    vib_a_seekBar.setProgress(vib_a_strength);
    vib_a_seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            vib_a_text_view.setText(getString(R.string.vib_a_progress, progress));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            vib_a_strength = seekBar.getProgress();
            editor.putInt(getString(R.string.vib_a_strength_shared), vib_a_strength);
            editor.commit();
        }
    });
}
```

Everything works fine, the three SeekBar states are updated correctly, but I have a Warning when I inspect my code.

It says: Formatting string ''vib_a_strength_shared'' is not referencing numbered arguments [1],
 Formatting string ''vib_b_strength_shared'' is not referencing numbered arguments [1, 2],
 Formatting string ''vib_c_strength_shared'' is not referencing numbered arguments [1, 2, 3]

My strings.xml looks like this:

```
<string name="vib_a_strength_shared">%2$d</string>
<string name="vib_b_strength_shared">%3$d</string>
<string name="vib_c_strength_shared">%4$d</string>
```

I know the correct way is to put %1$d as a placeholder, but if I put %1$d in this three string names, the SeekBar values are only set to one last changed value.
And not three different values.

I hope you can help me with this Formatting String Value Warning.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please try again with "%1$d" or simply "%d". This should work. If it doesn't, can you add a screenshot or the entire code (for all three methods)?

Comment: Now that I take a closer look, why is the key for your preferences a format string? editor.putInt(getString(R.string.vib_a_strength_shared), vib_a_strength); When you call getString on this string, it expects a format argument but you provide none.

Comment: Yes, now I changed it to: editor.putInt("vib_a_strength_shared", vib_b_strength); and so on, and it works fine for all three values. I hope this is the corrent way to set the Key.